# Difference between ? and @VarName parameters in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, conventions, parameterized-query, progress-db

I'm working on a vb.net program for in house use. I've been looking around and trying to understand what the best way to use parameterized queries is. I've seen many places that mention `@VarName` that would be used as `INSERT INTO people (FirstName,LastName) VALUES (@FName,@LName)` where each is their respective parameter, but I've also seen several places that say to use positional parameters as `?` used as `INSERT INTO people (FirstName,LastName) VALUES (?,?)` where the first parameter of `?` is FirstName and the second is LastName. I'm working with an OpenEdge Progress Database.

Which is the convention for VB.net, if there is one? What is the difference between them?

Comment: This does depend, to a great extent, on which database system(s) you're sending your queries to and via what data access technology.

Comment: Added tags for my database system

Comment: and I'm making these queries via ODBC

Answer (score 3):

@ Parameters are for the SQL Server native library (using the System.Data.SqlClient library) (or equiv: like Sybase, etc)  but ? parameters are for OLEDB (System.Data.OleDb)  They are not interchangeable.

Comment: I added what system I'm using. It's neither of these.

Comment: Chances are you're using OLEDB to connect to your datasource as it's a generic API for accessing data in a uniform manner. If you're not using System.Data.OleDb directly then I'd check the documentation for whatever driver you are using to see what it recommend using.

Comment: I am not familiar with Progress OpenEdge, but if it uses @ for parameters, then I would expect it to be similar (for this answer): use @ param with the native driver or ? param for the OLEDB drivers.